# twitter bootstrap datetimepicker not returning correct UTC Datetime by getDate function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using the latest bootstrap datetimepicker downloaded from [here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/dist/bootstrap-datetimepicker-0.0.10.zip) however facing issue in getting correct UTC datetime when using the API.

```
var dateTimePicker = jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
dateTimePicker.on('changeDate', function(e) {

var eventTarget = jQuery(e.target);

var picker = eventTarget.data('datetimepicker');

console.log( "getDate: " + picker.getDate());
console.log( "getLocalDate: " +  picker.getLocalDate());
console.log( "getLocalDate to UTC: " +  picker.getLocalDate().toUTCString());
```

output

```
 getDate: Wed Apr 24 2013 05:53:40 GMT+0530 (IST)

 getLocalDate: Wed Apr 24 2013 00:23:40 GMT+0530 (IST)

 getLocalDate to UTC: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 18:53:40 GMT
```

which shows that getLocalDate returns correct datetime in my timezone GMT +0530 and getLocalDate.toUTCString returns the corresponding UTC datetime for my local datetime.However getDate obviously is not returning the correct UTC datetime as per the [doc](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
   // Considering you are on a GMT-3 timezone and the input contains '2000-01-17 10:p'
   var localDate = picker.getLocalDate(); // localDate === 2000-01-17 07:00
   var utcDate = picker.getDate(); // utcDate === 2000-01-17 10:00
```

[In the source code](https://raw.github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js) I found following code which I am unable to understand.

```
 function UTCDate() {
   return new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, arguments));
 }
```

Can anybody please make me understand how the code snippet **new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, arguments))** works and what it should return?

At the time of writing this it was **Wed Apr 24 00:19** in my timezone GMT +0530 for which 
the UTCDate function mentioned above returned **Wed Apr 24 2013 05:48:49 GMT+0530 (IST)** which obviously is not the corresponding UTC DateTime for the datetime in my timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Date.UTC returns the number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1 1970.

The apply method is a javascript method that lets you call another method and pass to it the arguments of the parent method.

I'm thinking that this is trying to create a new date by passing it Date.UTC() as an initializer, using the arguments passed in to the UTCDate() method.